# How to validate a field of Zend_Form based on the value of another field?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I'm trying to add a custom validator to a field. It should take into account the value of another field. E.g. field A should be at most B+50%.

I've made a class implementing `Zend_Validate_Interface`, but apparently Zend Form only sends in the value of the current field to the validator. How do I make the validator receive everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `isValid` on a `Zend_Form` it will pass the all the data you passed to the method

```
$form->isValid(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2));
```

Your custom validator will receive that whole array of **raw values.**

**Example Validator**

```
class My_Validator_TwoVals implements Zend_Validate_Interface
{
    public function getMessages()
    {
        return array();
    }
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        print_r(func_get_args());
    }
}
```

**Example Form**

```
$f = new Zend_Form;
$a = $f->createElement('Text', 'a');
$b = $f->createElement('Text', 'b');
$b->addPrefixPath('My_Validator', '.', 'validate');
$b->addValidator('TwoVals');
$f->addElements(array($a, $b));

$f->isValid(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
        )
)
```

As you can see there was also a second argument passed to `isValid`, which is $context. And that contains the remaining values.

An **alternative** would be to pass the second element to match against as an option to the Validator, e.g.

```
class My_Validator_TwoVals implements Zend_Validate_Interface
{
    protected $a;
    public function getMessages()
    {
        return array();
    }
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        var_dump($this->a->getValue());
    }
    public function __construct(Zend_Form_Element $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
```

**Setup**

```
$f = new Zend_Form;
$a = $f->createElement('Text', 'a');
$b = $f->createElement('Text', 'b');
$b->addPrefixPath('My_Validator', '.', 'validate');
$b->addValidator('TwoVals', false, array($a));
$f->addElements(array($a, $b));

$f->isValid(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2));
```

Will then print `int(1)`. As you can see, we fetched that value through the form element's API so anything you configured for validators and filters would be applied, e.g. it's not the raw value. And you can also set it to another value, etc.

Also have a look at `Zend_Validate_Identical` to learn how ZF implements checking of other form elements:

- http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/Identical.php

Comment: Well, I think you're wrong with the first part. You call `isValid` on `$b` instead of `$f`. I've checked it before posting and calling `isValid` on the form does *not* send all the data to element's `isValid`. Reading further through the response - it's rather big)

Comment: @Fluffy my bad, sorry. Still, it's correct though. See my update. The full array will be in $context.

Comment: Actually you're right. No idea why there is no mentioning of it in the Zend_Validate_Interface documentation. Thanks, I guess this is what I was looking for

Comment: @Fluffy I assume its because it would break backwards compatibility if they changed the isValid signature on the interface. All validators implementing that would have to change their methods to include $context then to match the interface definition.